# where have all my decorations gone?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

where have all my decorations gone?  I had decorated 12 levels yesterday morning.  When I went back to check my game that afternoon I only had one that was decorated... whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

The Emperor will remove the decorations.  He feels they don't truly represent the deadly implications of the Death Star.